# How to setup TypeORM, express with Serverless Framework, AWS Lambda, AWS API Gateway

Tags: mysql, express, aws-lambda, typeorm, serverless-framework

I already have a project in TypeORM typescript using NodeJS, Express with MySQL and want to connect with AWS Lambda and AWS API Gateway using Serverless Framework, I can't find any configuration official serverless docs or anywhere on the internet.
Here's my serverless.yml file

```
service: ${file(./secret.json):ApiName}
provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs14.x
    region: ${file(./secret.json):DefaultRegion}
    stage: prod-erm

functions:
  
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ######################################################### below are examples

    bye: #This Is an example
        handler: src/middleware/test_res.bye
        events:
            - http:
                  path: /byea
                  method: get
        cors: true
        origin: "*"

    hello: #This Is an example
        handler: src/middleware/test_res.hello
        # vpc:
        #   securityGroupIds:
        #     - Fn::GetAtt: ServerlessVPC.DefaultSecurityGroup
        #   subnetIds:
        #     - Ref: ServerlessSubnetA
        events:
            - http:
                  path: /hello
                  method: get
        cors: true
        origin: "*"

    crud: #This Is an example
        handler: src/middleware/test_query.query
        # vpc:
        #   securityGroupIds:
        #     - Fn::GetAtt: ServerlessVPC.DefaultSecurityGroup
        #   subnetIds:
        #     - Ref: ServerlessSubnetA
        events:
            - http:
                  path: /query
                  method: post
        cors: true
        origin: "*"
        headers: "*"

plugins:
    - serverless-offline
    - serverless-pseudo-parameters
```

and ormconfig.json file

```
{
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "remotemysql.com",
    "port": "3306",
    "username": // <username>,
    "password": // <password>,
    "database": // <dbname>,
    "synchronize": false,
    "logging": true,
    "entities": ["src/entities/*.ts"],
    "migrations": ["src/database/migrations/*ts"],
    "cli": {
        "migrationDir": "src/database/migrations",
        "entitiesDir": "src/entities"
    }
}
```

and connection code

```
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';

createConnection();
```

```
// server.js
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'express-async-errors';
import express, {Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
import {json, urlencoded} from 'body-parser';
// import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

import router from './routes';

import './database';

// parsing the request
const app = express();
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(json());

// PORT number
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Dotenv default config
// dotenv.config({ path: __dirname + '/.env' })

// using routes
app.use(router);

// Custom error handling
app.use(
    (err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        if (err instanceof Error) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: err.message,
              });
        }

        return res.status(500).json({
            status: 'error',
            message: 'Internal Server Error',
          })
    }
);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on ${PORT}`));
```

if anyone has done before please help me thanks

Comment: Any luck finding an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I could not find any solution @BioAbnerJ